# A slider created with d3.slider.js will not allow movement to last value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Based on this example(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZPpWy) I tried to adapt the Slider with ordinal scales, to have more values.

But the slider I created does not seem to move to the last value.

I have created a codepen displaying this behavior:

```
data = ["1890-1914", "1914-1930", "1930-1950", "1950-1970", "1970-1980", "1990-2006", "2006-2018"]

  essai = d3.slider().scale(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data).rangePoints([0, 1], 0.5)).axis(d3.svg.axis()).snap(true).value("1890-1914");
```

https://codepen.io/rhys-newbury/pen/RYvxyd

Is this an issue caused by my code?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope it's got nothing to do with your code. It's the following line in the **d3 slider plugin** that's causing the issue.

In the **moveHandle** function, I've got no idea why this comparison is done as it messes up normal ordinal (string based) scales as well but anyway here's the line:

```
if ( value[ 0 ] >= value[ 1 ] ) return;
```

Commenting out this line, here's a fork of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLe9ht1z/2/

I'm quite sure this won't break any of the functionalities the plugin provides but if it still concerns you, I suggest you write an own plugin for ordinal scales - should be fairly easy.

Hope this helps.